# Text clustering of 200 different words

Tags: python, cluster-computing

I have data of 200 different words in a one column.I want to make the clusters of these words.I have applied k means but the output contain same words in each cluster.Kindly suggest the algorithm or code in python so that i am able to make clusters of different words.

Comment: Maybe you could provide your code and part of your data?

Comment: I thought cluster computing was groups of computers working together. What do you mean by clusters of words?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.